# HTML Email within VBA - Remove Space after unordered list

Tags: html, vba, outlook

I'm trying to remove a space after the bolded "Header" and before my "bullets" in my HTML email within VBA. I've included my code and a picture of its output below. I've seen posts using CSS in HTML but I'm not sure how to access that through VBA... Help would be appreciated!

```
 With OMail
.Display
End With
    signature = OMail.HTMLbody
With OMail
.Subject = "Subject"
.HTMLbody = "<style> ul {margin-top:0px;} li {margin-left:10px;}</style> " _
& "Unbulleted Text" _
& "<br>" & "<br>" & "<b>Header</b>" _
& "<ul>" & "<li>" & "bullet one" _
& "</li>" & "<li>" & "bullet two" _
& "</li>" & "<li>" & "bullet three" _
& "</li>" & "</ul>" & "Unbulleted Text"
End With
```

The above code has been modified to represent proposed solutions below, however the result is still the same (see picture) 
[image]

Comment: That added 3 spaces in a new line beneath the bolded header. If i delete the 3 spaces, the text appears as it does in the first image above. So it still has the space after header

Comment: Try saving the raw html into some .html file, then open it in IE and use developer tools (F12) to tweak the CSS & styling until you get the desired formatting.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon it looks like he was adding the style line inside of the UL element... for some reason...

Comment: @braX CSS is enough of a PITA as it is... *inline* CSS is a nightmare =)

Comment: @MathieuGuindon agreed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add a margin-top:0px; to your li it did the trick for me.  Not sure why it didn't inherit the setting from the ul but it fixes your issue at least :)

`.HTMLBody = "<style> ul {margin-top:0px;} li {margin-left:50px;margin-top:0px;}</style> " _
& "Unbulleted Text" _
& "<br>" & "<br>" & "<b>Header</b>" _
& "<ul>" & "<li>" & "bullet one" _
& "</li>" & "<li>" & "bullet two" _
& "</li>" & "<li>" & "bullet three" _
& "</li>" & "</ul>" & "Unbulleted Text"`

Answer (score 2):

Add CSS/Styles it like any other string.

In this case you want to remove the margin from your `ul` element:

`"<style> ul {margin:0px;} </style>"`

If you dont want to remove the bottom margin too, then use this:

`"<style> ul {margin-top:0px;} </style>"`

If it's affecting the `li` elements for some reason, try using this:

`"<style> ul {margin-top:0px;} li {margin-left:50px;}</style>"`

<sub>Note: it's adding margin-top to the UL but adding margin-left to the LI.</sub>

You can add that string before or after your HTML (but not mixed inside of the html elements as seen in the comments), it doesn't matter, but most people put styles at the top, before the HTML.

---

```
.HTMLbody = "<style> ul {margin-top:0px;} li {margin-left:50px;}</style> " _ 
& "Unbulleted Text" _
& "<br>" & "<br>" & "<b>Header</b>" _
& "<ul>" & "<li>" & "bullet one" _
& "</li>" & "<li>" & "bullet two" _
& "</li>" & "<li>" & "bullet three" _
& "</li>" & "</ul>" & "Unbulleted Text"
```

Comment: This works but removes the left indent from the bullets.. Is there a way to avoid that?

Comment: Hmm.. Both options give the same result. They remove the space after but also remove the left indent and leave all of the text left aligned. Sorry - what do you mean by browser?

Comment: My default browser is chrome.. the macro will export text from excel to Outlook.

Comment: Thanks for your help - if it makes any difference, changing margin top and left to 50px has no effect

Comment: No effect unfortunately

Comment: And in your first attempt at adding `margin-left` to it, you didnt add that to the style for the `ul` with the `margin-top`, did you? It's intended for the `li`, not the `ul`

Comment: so `& "<ul>" & "<style> ul {margin-top:0px;} li {margin-left:10px;}</style>" & "bullet one" _` ? This removes the bullet point from "Bullet One" and adds the space we are trying to remove after it. Then bullets two and three are still bulleted. They all have the correct indent though

Comment: all else the same as the original code, the following have no effect 
`.HTMLbody = "<style> ul {margin-top:0px;} </style> Unbulleted Text" _` 
`.HTMLbody = "<style> ul {margin-top:0px;} </style> Unbulleted Text" _` 
`.HTMLbody = "<style> ul {margin-top:0px;} li {margin-left:10px;}</style> Unbulleted Text" _`

Comment: You are confusing a `Stylesheet` and `inline styles`  - they are similar, but different.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion - your refreshed answer is what I had. I was trying to say i tried all three solutions you proposed in the .HTMLbody line with no success

Comment: Got a bit lost with all the updates on this one, but had you tried adding the margin-top  in the li styling.  It removed the spacing after Header  `.HTMLBody = "<style> ul {margin-top:0px;} li {margin-left:50px;margin-top:0px;}</style> " _`

Comment: @ACCtionMan if you post as answer i'll accept it as the correct answer. Thanks